# Problema (parece que de compilador) C++

Tags: c++, linux, ubuntu

Escribí este pequeño programa que suma los elementos de un vector, lo que pasa es que al intentar compilarlo y ejecutarlo (en ubuntu 20.04) con la herramienta g++, me sale un resultado obviamente erroneo, aca un ejemplo:

```
Digite el numero de elementos del vector: 3
1. Digite un numero: 1
2. Digite un numero: 2
3. Digite un numero: 3
La suma de los elementos del vector es: -489246634
```

el codigo en cuestion es este:

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

int vec[100],tam;

void PedirDatos();
int CalcularSuma(int vec[],int);

int main(){
    PedirDatos();

    cout<<"La suma de los elementos del vector es: "<<CalcularSuma(vec,tam)<<endl;

    return 0;
}

void PedirDatos(){
    cout<<"Digite el numero de elementos del vector: ";
    cin>>tam;

    for(int i=0;i<tam;i++){
        cout<<i+1<<". Digite un numero: ";
        cin>>vec[i];
    }
}

int CalcularSuma(int vec[],int tam){
    int suma;

    for(int i=0;i<tam;i++){
        suma += vec[i];
    }

    return suma;
}
```

Y las respuestas pueden variar, tipo no es que siempre salga la misma respuesta.
Y no, no es un error de sintaxis puesto que lo he probado en una shell de C++ online y el codigo corre perfectamente, alguen sabe cual es el problema? o que compilador puedo usar?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No solo no es error del compilador, sino que el compilador te pudo ayudar a resolver tu problema.

Si compilas con avisos (`-Wall -Wextra`, y te recomendaria tambien usar `-Werror`), te sale lo siguiente:

```
main.cpp:33:9: warning: variable 'suma' is uninitialized when used here [-Wuninitialized]
        suma += vec[i];
        ^~~~
main.cpp:30:13: note: initialize the variable 'suma' to silence this warning
    int suma;
            ^
             = 0
1 warning generated.
```

Y es que en tu funcion `CalcularSuma`:

```
int CalcularSuma(int vec[],int tam){
    int suma;

    for(int i=0;i<tam;i++){
        suma += vec[i];
    }

    return suma;
}
```

La variable suma no tiene ningun valor inicial. Si no le asignas un valor inicial cuando corra va a tener un valor basura. Por eso es buena idea siempre inicializar las variables.

Un par de recomendaciones que no van relacionadas con tu pregunta:

- No uses variables globales. Conforme tus programas crezcan se complicaran mucho mas.
- No es para que lo corrijas ahora, pero ten presente que usar `using namespace std;` no es buena idea
- En lugar de usar un array estilo C, en C++ tienes `std::array`. Cumple con el array estilo C, y tiene mas funcionalidades, como iteradores.
- Si no sabes la cantidad de datos, en lugar de declarar un array grande, mejor seria que usaras `std::vector`